# How to add public ssh key in putty

Tags: ssh, passwords, putty, authentication

So, I was given a public key and asked -among other things- to set up ssh key authentication only and to add a user to my server that could log in to the server with this public key. I created another user eg userTest to test if my implementation is correct.

The thing is that once I am connected to my root account (via password, although I should perhaps make this with ssh-key authentication too) and I type ssh userTest@ip_address I can connect without a password. But then, when typing ssh root@ip_address to get back to the root account a need a password.

However, what puzzles me is that the userTest public key doesn't show to authorized_keys but can connect whereas the root's public key that appears there cannot connect without a password. (However, when launching Putty from the userTest account it needs the password).

I've seen lots of tutorials and I've modified my sshd_config file but I obviously do something wrong as I can't connect without passwords.

So, what should I do?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

[image: image3]
[image: image4]

**Where the purple mark is userTest**

Comment: Post your sshd_config as a start

Comment: Please post configuration files as **text**, not as an screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I should have:

1. Create ssh key for root eg by PuttyGen [link1](https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-authentication)
2. Add user USER1
3. Create key for USER1 eg by PuttyGen
4. Add USER1's public key in /home/**USER1**/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. If you have the private key add it to Putty [link2](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/)
6. Make sure that (*in root directories*) you have adjusted the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file properly (PermitRootLogin, allow Users, PublicKeyAuthentication, passwordAuthentication and others mentioned in above links etc) and then run `service sshd restart` so the changes take effect.
7. Enjoy!